# Someone committed in our central repository. How do we revert it?

Tags: mercurial

We're using a local central repository where everyone pushes to and pulls from. Until recently this repository only contained the .hg folder. Then someone went ahead and committed directly in the central repository creating an "island" changeset with no parent (parent = -1) nor child. The correct way would have been to add it in a local repository and push the changes.

Is there any way to get the working copy of the central repository to get back to the state where it only contain .hg and not be associated with a specific changeset?

Comment: Respectfully, now knowing what you where after, I find your question very unclear.  I mention it only because you are an active participant rather that a 1-time user.  For example, the discussion in haarrgh's answer is confusion about whether you mean the "working directory"/"working copy" or the repository (the files under control and their history - essentially everything in the .hg folder).  Its helpful to distinguish between the two, where, in your point of view, they seem the same. Again, I mean no disrespect, I just want to get everyone on the same page (terms) for future questions.

Comment: Rereading my question I realize that. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command:

```
hg update null
```

Updates a repository's working directory to the point before the first commit, so there are no files in the working directory and `hg parents` shows `-1`.

You'll still need to remove the commit if you don't want it, but that's a separate question/issue.

Comment: Great point @BertF.  I've updated the answer to include the working copy qualifier.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is your local central repository and these are commands that **edit history**, please take every precaution, like trying things out on a copy of the repository first.

- `hg rollback` (to remove the last repository change)

  https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Rollback

> Roll back the last transaction in a repository.

- `hg strip` (to remove specific revisions)

  https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Strip

> hg strip rev removes the rev revision and all its descendants from a repository.

- Also see:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/EditingHistory

> If you catch your mistake immediately (or reasonably soon), you can just use ***hg strip REV*** to roll back the latest (one or more) changes. ...

***Edit: This answers the question in its original form.  The OP has since edited the question.***

Comment: Ry4an gave the answer I needed, but your is the logical next step. If I could check two answers I would. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just delete everything except the `.hg` folder.

Comment: The OP said that the change was already committed, therefore deleting the files in the working copy will not help - the problem is in the repository (the .hg folder)

Comment: If I understood the OP correctly, he **wants** the change in the central repository 
(Quote: "The correct way would have been to add it in a local repository and push the changes."). He just wants to get rid of the **working copy** in his central repository.

Comment: I think that last change was checked in as a strange branch off the initial root rev (`"island" changeset with no parent`).  I think they want to undo the change and then check in into its proper place in the rev tree.

Comment: Deleting everything except `.hg` is like doing `hg revert null` -- it changes the working directory but not the `parent` as seen by `hg parents`.  You want `hg update null` which alters both the files in the working dir and the repos conception of what's currently checked out.

Comment: We don't want the change in the central repository. We're currently migrating to Mercurial and a colleague made a newbie mistake thinking it was ok to commit in the central repository. We want the central repository to be "null". Thanks all. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what happened, someone changed into the repository directory and committed a single file as an 'added file' without first checking out any changeset from the active directory.

What you ended up with is something like the following history graph:

```
0:a43f   1:2843   2:bc81   3:2947
 o ------ o ------ o ------ o

4:228f
 o
```

where changeset *4:228f* has the "*null id*" as its parent changeset.

Depending on whether you want to keep changeset 4:228f or not, you can follow one of the following strategies:

#### Option 1: Clone the repository without the offending change

You can create a new clone of the repository, specifying revision 3:2947 as the *target* revision.  This will pull change 3:2947 and all its *ancestor changesets* into the new repository.  Since the offending changeset is not linked into the ancestry of changeset 3:2947, it will not be part of the new clone.

I recommend saving the old repository first, and then moving everything over to a new clone, e.g. any repository-specific setup files you keep in its `.hg/` directory.

If your current repository lives in `/work/repo/foo`, one way to do this would be:

```
$ cd /work/repo
$ mv foo foo.bak
$ hg clone -r 2947 foo.bak newfoo
```

Now copy over any `.hg/` setup files, e.g. your original `.hg/hgrc` file:

```
$ cp foo.bak/.hg/hgrc newfoo/.hg/hgrc
```

Finally move the new `foo` repository in place:

```
$ mv newfoo foo
```

#### Option 2: Clone the repository and keep but *rebase* the change

Do the same as before, but before you move the `newfoo` repository in place, use the "*hg export*" command to extract a copy of the offending change from the old repository.  Then check out a working copy of the tip-most changeset in the `newfoo` tree and import the file changes of the offending change as a normal changeset of your current history graph.

So, right before `mv newfoo foo`, save the patch of the offending change by typing:

```
$ cd /work/repo/foo.bak
$ hg export -r 228f --git > /tmp/patchfile.diff
```

then you can check-out the latest revision of the new repository, and re-import the patch on top of your current history:

```
$ cd /work/repo/newfoo
$ hg update --clean tip
$ hg import /tmp/patchfile.diff
```

If the offending changeset merely adds a new file, this should work fine and you are ready to move the new repository in place!

Before doing the final rename though, it may be a good idea to remove the working-copy files of the new repository:

```
$ cd /work/repo/newfoo
$ hg update --clean null
```